# Multiple ArrayLists... how to efficiently find elements that occur in two or more lists?

Tags: java

I have a variable number of ArrayLists. What is the most efficient means of determining the elements that occur in two or more of the lists?

For example:

[apple, banana, orange]

[kiwi, apple, grape]

[pear, grape, apple]

[blueberry, avocado, kiwi]

I need a function that returns:

[apple, kiwi, grape]

What is the most efficient way to do this? I could have hundreds of arrays each with hundreds of elements.

Comment: Can you have `[apple, apple]` as one of your arrays?

Comment: Use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to count the occurrences.

Comment: Or use a Set and take the intersection of the sets in question.  You'd only need to do this once to find all elements in common, and then could cache the result.

Comment: Implementation note:  this looks like a big n^3 problem, but it's not.  The first two lists have an intersection of just [apple], which is then a synch to intersect with the third set, time-wise.  If you intersect your smallest sets first, you'll get smaller sets to intersect at later steps, saving time.

Comment: @markspace I may be misunderstanding you, but I don’t want to find all the elements in common across all arrays. I am not looking for the intersection of all arrays. I am looking for the elements that appear in two or more arrays.

Comment: Well obviously you should do it for the two (or more) that you are interested in.  You can still cache the result.

Comment: This is an opinion based question that can gather many different answers. @porkfried42 I suggest you try solving this yourself by choosing a method in your own terms, and then asking to help you optimize it or complete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hundreds of arrays with hundreds of elements then you don't need to worry about efficiency. Even a very inefficient solution will complete very quickly on modern HW. I suggest you focus on elegance of solution and consider efficiency only if you have to.

You have said that these are lists so I'm assuming there can be duplicates in each list - i.e. if an item occurs twice in just one list then it's not considered as occurring in 'two or more lists'.

```
List<List<String>> input;
Map<String,Long> occurrences = input.stream()
    .flatMap(l -> l.stream().distinct())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l, Collectors.counting()));
```

This calculates the number of lists containing each item. You could get all items with 2 or more occurrences with `occurrences.keySet().stream().filter(i -> occurrences.get(i) > 1)`